# Regarding data bind with excel sheet

Tags: testing, telerik, automation, telerik-test-studio

I created Excel sheet in that i created one column with name"Item"

First i add the excel sheet to my test then am trying to do bind .

In the-bind test to data source window am selecting my excel file then am trying to select sheet from select table drop down that time telerik test studio automatically closing.

why it is closing

please give solution.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

This is the application issue and is not related to the adding of 'data source' to the test script. You can raise a ticket for this with the telerik suppport people and they will most probably give you the latest internal build, which you can install and hopefully this will resolve the crash issue.